# Existence of a limit of a function given that the derivative at the point exists

Tags: limits, derivatives

Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $a$, and $f'(a)$ exists. Does the limit
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x) - f(2a -x)}{2(x-a)}$$
always exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin {align} \lim_{x \mathop \to a} \frac {f(x)-f(2a - x)} {2(x-a)} &= \frac12\lim_{x \mathop \to a} \left(\frac {f(x)-f(a)} {x-a} + \frac {f(a)-f(2a - x)} {x-a}\right)\\&= \frac12\left(\lim_{x \mathop \to a} \frac {f(x)-f(a)} {x-a} + \lim_{x \mathop \to a}\frac {f(a)-f(2a - x)} {x-2a+a}\right)\\&= \frac12\left(\lim_{x \mathop \to a} \frac {f(x)-f(a)} {x-a} + \lim_{u \mathop \to a}\frac {f(a)-f(u)} {-u+a}\right)\end{align}$$

The last equation uses the substitution $u = 2a - x$. Since $f'(a)$ exists you know how to fill out the rest.

Comment: I wouldn't write it thus as a single equation-chain, as that occludes the crucial logical step: if both $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}h(x)$ are finite, then $\lim_{x\to a}(g(x)+h(x))$ exists / is finite too and equals $\lim_{x\to a}(g(x)+h(x))$. However it is not in general valid to split up the limit over a sum into a sum of limits to assess existance/finiteness.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$ we have

$$f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+o(x-a)$$

$$f(2a-x)=f(a)+f'(a)(a-x)+o(x-a)$$

therefore

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x) - f(2a -x)}{2(x-a)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{2f'(a)(x-a)+o(x-a)}{2(x-a)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{2f'(a)+o(1)}{2}=f'(a)$$